# Google sheets: Selecting the column with the highest value and pulling a string from a specific cell in its row

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

From a sheet of data, I need to determine the highest value in a column, which I can achieve with `=Max()`

Once I've obtained that value I need to return the corresponding row name that it sits in.

[image: for example if the highest value in the column is 618 as shown then the value P E T S should return]

Answer (score 0):

What I have understood from your question is there is some data under column A and B as shown below (Click on Run code snippet to check the values in table) and the result you want is the name of the adjacent cell having  **max(B1:B7)**

then select cell C1 and use this formula you will get your answer

**=vlookup(Max(B1:B7),{B1:B7,A1:A7},2,False)**

```html
<table border=1>
  <th>
    Column A
  </th>
  <th>
    Column B
  </th>
  <tr>
    <td>
      ABC
    </td>
    <td>
      9
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      DEF
    </td>
    <td>
      112
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      GHI
    </td>
    <td>
      20
    </td>

    <tr>
      <td>
        PETS
      </td>
      <td>
        618
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        JKL
      </td>
      <td>
        10
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        MNO
      </td>
      <td>
        25
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Your correct other than the format the date is in, I've tried to apply your response to the situation but no luck, 

If i could link the document to better explain myself, https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11AwXztmkX_0d6-xlioVrtYbUtJr6A7RAveCuFVng0Lk/edit#gid=1197625268

The max values have already been collated in "leaderboard" from "refined_data" I had to break it down to remove what wasnt useful from "data_import", I've followed the format you've shown using Vlookup but can't get it to work.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11AwXztmkX_0d6-xlioVrtYbUtJr6A7RAveCuFVng0Lk/edit?usp=sharing, apologies i supplied the incorrect link

Comment: Hey @Charlie,

I saw your leaderboard sheet but it seems there are some errors under column rank 2 and rank3 .
I am not sure what exactly data you want there so I didn't change anything on that sheet yet. Will you manage those columns again?  and please tell me which data you want to fetch from it. I will surely help on this.